# Why is Future[Set[Unit]] not accepted as Future[Unit]?

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion

A common gotcha when working with futures is that when you expect `Future[Unit]`, even `Future[Future[Unit]]` will be accepted (see e.g. [Why Shouldn’t You Use Future[Unit] as a Return Type in a Scala Program](https://medium.com/swlh/why-shouldnt-you-use-future-unit-as-a-return-type-in-a-scala-program-a4c58f95b343)).

I was surprised recently `Future.sequence(setOfFutures)` is not accepted in such situation:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val set = Set(Future(()))

def fuu: Future[Unit] = {
  Future.sequence(set)
}
```

With Scala 2.12.13 I get error:

> type mismatch;
>
> found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Unit]]

With Scala 2.13 I get:

> Cannot construct a collection of type Unit with elements of type Unit based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]].

When I change the body of the function to:

```
  val s = Future.sequence(set)
  s
```

I get set the same error as before.

Why is `Future[Future[Unit]]` accepted as a `Future[Unit]` and `Future[Set[Unit]]` or `Future[List[Unit]]` is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the signature of `Future.sequence` in Scala 2.13

```
def sequence[A, CC[X] <: IterableOnce[X], To](in: CC[Future[A]])(
  implicit 
  bf: BuildFrom[CC[Future[A]], A, To], 
  executor: ExecutionContext
): Future[To]
```

so given

```
val set = Set(Future(()))
def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence(set)
```

then inference will assign type paramers of `sequence` like so

```
To = Unit
A = Unit
CC = Set
```

For example consider `fuu`'s return type `Future[Unit] = Future[To]`. Hence we have

```
def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence[Unit, Set, Unit](set)
```

so compiler needs to implicitly assign `bf` parameter

```
scala> implicitly[BuildFrom[Set[Future[Unit]], Unit, Unit]]
                 ^
       error: Cannot construct a collection of type Unit with elements of type Unit based on a collection of type Set[scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]].
```

Now consider Scala 2.12 signature of `Future.sequence`

```
def sequence[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[Future[A]])(
  implicit 
  cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]],A,M[A]],
  executor: ExecutionContext
): Future[M[A]]
```

so given

```
val set = Set(Future(()))
def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence(set)
```

inference becomes

```
A = Unit
M = Set
```

so we have

```
def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence[Unit, Set](set)
```

where compiler can successfully implicitly assign `cbf` parameter

```
scala>  implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Set[Future[Unit]],Unit,Set[Unit]]]
res4: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Set[scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]],Unit,Set[Unit]] = scala.collection.generic.GenSetFactory$$anon$1@1bff70a6
```

hence we effectively have in 2.12 the following situation

```
scala> def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence(set) : Future[Set[Unit]]
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Set[Unit]]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]
def fuu: Future[Unit] = Future.sequence(set) : Future[Set[Unit]]
```

This should explain the difference between the two compiler error messages between the two Scala versions is not related to value discarding but to how inference assigned the corresponding types.

Comment: I see now. The premise of my question is wrong: `Future[Future[Unit]]` is not accepted as `Future[Unit]`. The `Future(Future(()))` is rewritten as `Future(Future(()), ())` instead when defined where `Future[Unit]` is expected.

Comment: Note: it seems the value discarding rewriting has changed in Scala 3, as with it the code ```def foo: Future[Unit] = Future(Future(()))``` is no longer accepted and gives error *Found:    scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] Required: Unit*.

Comment: I found the answer unsatisfying because I didn't see the moving parts. It fails because it doesn't have a builder `BuildFrom[Set[Future[Unit]], Unit, Unit]`. I can implement that. Maybe it runs everything on a special context as a side-effect. I understand the OP is asking why doesn't value discard kick in somehow.